# vb.net form load and render speed too slow

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have a mdi parent form which, when clicking a specific button on the screen, opens a new child form. When this form loads, it needs to call the database to retrieve information, the problem is that the form takes a lot of time to load, like 15 seconds, there's not too much code in the load sub, also, I tried to remove the database code from the load event, and, although it did make it a little faster, it still takes some time to load, is there a way to fix this?

This is my form

[image]

This is my code

```
Public Class Deposito
Dim FormPadre As MDICajero = New MDICajero
Private monedas As ArrayList = New ArrayList
Private Sub Deposito_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    FormPadre = Me.MdiParent
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim ProximoForm As MenuPrincipal = New MenuPrincipal
    FormPadre.LimpiarForm()
    ProximoForm.MdiParent = FormPadre
    ProximoForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    ProximoForm.Show()
    ProximoForm.CargaMenu(1)
End Sub

Private Sub BDepositar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BDepositar.Click
    Dim dato As Emovimientos = New Emovimientos
    dato.monto = montodeposito.Text
    dato.idcuenta = nrocuenta.Text
    dato.fecha = fechacobro.Value

End Sub End class
```

I've worked with java before and never seen so much load time between forms, even when retrieving information off a database.

EDIT: added a few lines to the constructor to make the form load faster, however, the rendering process it's still buggy.

```
Sub New()
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer Or ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub
```

EDIT 2: on the MDI parent form i used the same code that is automatically written when adding a mdi form to your solution, the only thing i added was an event for when the buttons are pressed to open the child forms:

```
Private Sub BRetiro_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BRetiro.Click
    Dim ProximoForm As Retiro = New Retiro
    Me.LimpiarForm()
    ProximoForm.MdiParent = Me
    ProximoForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    ProximoForm.Show()
End Sub
```

This is the code of the "LimpiarForm" function:

```
 Public Sub LimpiarForm()
    'borro todos los form hijos para no ocupar memoria, debe ser lo primero que tengo que hacer
    Dim num As Integer
    For num = 0 To Me.MdiChildren.Count - 1
        Dim a = Me.MdiChildren(num)
        a.Dispose()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Profile your code so you know how long each part is taking so that you know where the bottle neck is.  I would start with your database code, because 15 seconds is a long time to load something.  Forms and controls aren't going to be your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's probably because your form has a lot of controls, the best way to load it smoothly is to set the opacity of the form to `0` and create a timer and run it on form load, and inside the timer you increase the opacity of the form by `0.05` or something like that.

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily I totally disagree with that ive had many forms with many controls load and never had any problems I would be more to think it's coming from databse connection.

Comment: @Mederic , Well i have experienced that before, so that why i said it, but i think you'er right because 15 seconds is too much.

Comment: the database code isn't a problem since i can put it in another place (which i did since it takes a lot), i added a few lines to make it faster (i'll add them in an edit), now it loads in about 2 or 4 seconds. However, it still doesn't render correctly. the problem is that i have many forms in this mdi parent, but only one can show at a time, what i did is dispose the old form when switching to a new one, maybe i should keep them in memory so they load faster. what do you think?, i don't think having 5 forms on memory isn't a good thing

Comment: Could you show us the child form's code so we can see if there's anything else that might cause it to be so slow? Also no, you shouldn't keep the forms in memory because it is a waste and will not really speed things up anyway (forms take very little memory so it's not the loading into memory that takes time).

Comment: all the code in the question is the child form's code. The parent's code is the same that's automatically written when creating a new MDI form, the only thing i added was the code to open a new child, i'll add it to the question